# Did the AIA remove the requirement of naming all the true inventors?

Tags: inventorship

If there are co inventors and one inventor files for and then receives a patent, under the new AIA laws can the co inventor invalidate the patent, or get his name on the patent that issued?  It seems to me that first to file means nothing if ALL true inventors must still be named.

Comment: "It seems to me that first to file means nothing if ALL true inventors must still be named." How so?

Answer (score 1):

*I do not see how this relates to first-to-file at all*.

All inventors need to be named but if they are not named or if the named inventors includes people who should not have been listed, the patent can be fixed later as long as everybody in question signs off on what the correct inventorship should have been. Pre-AIA it was possible to end up with an invalid patent even if all true inventors and incorrectly included non-inventors agreed on the proper inventorship later. Pre-AIA there was a requirement that "no deceptive intent" was involved in the original filing. Now that has been eliminated.

Pre-AIA if X filed as sole inventor (with deceptive intent) and later Y and Z caught up to him and asserted their co-inventorship, even if X was persuaded to fix it, legally, he couldn't (due to his original deceptive intent) and all three were screwed because it was wrong and couldn't be fixed. Now it can be fixed without worrying about orignal deceptiveness.

This is from the USPTO AIA FAQ:

> An inventor must state in his/her oath/declaration that (i) he/she is
>   an original inventor of the claimed invention; and (ii) he/she
>   authorized the filing of the patent application for the claimed
>   invention.  An inventor is **no longer required to (i) state that he/she
>   is the first inventor** of the claimed invention; (ii) state that the
>   application filing is made without deceptive intent; or (iii) provide
>   his/her country of citizenship.

Comment: I guess what I'm wondering about with first to file is ownership of the patent that issues. If I pay for the patent and get it, and then someone else who independently invented comes up and asserts he is an inventor, do I have to put his name on my patent and then deal with co ownership? Or how about a co inventor I worked with? I thought first to file meant that the first one who files gets the ownership of the patent, so long as that person is an original inventor.

Comment: Multiple people are listed on a patent if they are co-inventors. Someone who *independently* invented is completely different. If you file first (and didn't get the idea from them) then you would get the patent.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Patents. We try to make a distinction between questions, answers and comments. Your "answer" should have posted as a comment or as an edit to your question. Answering your own question is fine, as long as it is actually an answer. This structure helps all Stack Exchange sites be more organized and useful than general free-form discussion boards.